# URL Redirection not working

Tags: python, url, redirect

The following is the code I use,

```
import unshortenit 

unshortened_uri,status = unshortenit.unshorten('http://4sq.com/1iyfyI5')

print unshortened_uri

print status
```

The following is the output:

```
https://foursquare.com/edtechschools/checkin/53ac1e5f498e5d8d736ef3be?s=BlinbPzgFfShr0vdUnbEJUnOYYI&ref=tw

Invalid URL u'/tanyaavrith/checkin/53ac1e5f498e5d8d736ef3be?s=BlinbPzgFfShr0vdUnbEJUnOYYI&ref=tw': No schema supplied
```

whereas if I use the same url in browser, it correctly redirects to the actual url. Any idea why its not working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a 301 redirect chain:

```
From:
'http://4sq.com/1iyfyI5'

To:
'https://foursquare.com/edtechschools/checkin/53ac1e5f498e5d8d736ef3be?s=BlinbPzgFfShr0vdUnbEJUnOYYI&ref=tw'

To:
'/tanyaavrith/checkin/53ac1e5f498e5d8d736ef3be?s=BlinbPzgFfShr0vdUnbEJUnOYYI&ref=tw'
```

`unshortenit` use requests, <del>and requests can't understand the last relative url</del>.

Updates:

Actually, `request` lib can handle http redirects well and automatically with `request.get` method.

e.g.

```
import requests
r=requests.get('http://4sq.com/1iyfyI5')
r.status_code # 200
r.url # u'https://foursquare.com/tanyaavrith/checkin/53ac1e5f498e5d8d736ef3be?s=BlinbPzgFfShr0vdUnbEJUnOYYI&ref=tw'
```

But `unshortenit` does not want the overhead of HTTP GET, instead it uses HTTP HEAD. If the response of the HTTP Head request has a 'Location'field in its header, `unshortenit` makes a new HTTP HEAD request to that location. The new request is isolated from the original request, and relative url doesn't work any more.

Reference (from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location)):

> While the obsolete IETF standard RFC 2616 (HTTP 1.1) requires a
>   complete **absolute URI** for redirection, the most popular web
>   browsers **tolerate** the passing of a relative URL as the value for a
>   Location header field. Consequently, the current revision of HTTP/1.1
>   makes relative URLs conforming